# Empty req.files array when sending image/video blobs from React Native Expo to Express.js server

Tags: express, axios, expo, blob

**Problem**:

I'm encountering an issue where the `req.files` array is empty on my Express.js server when attempting to upload image/video files from a React Native Expo frontend.

**Relevant code:**

*Frontend (React Native Expo):*

```
/**
 * The function prepares form data by appending image, video, and text message to a FormData object.
 * @param imageUri - The imageUri parameter is the URI (Uniform Resource Identifier) of the image file
 * that you want to include in the form data.
 * @param videoUri - The `videoUri` parameter is the URI (Uniform Resource Identifier) of a video file.
 * It is used to fetch the video file and append it to the `formData` object.
 * @param textMessage - The text message parameter is a string that represents the message you want to
 * include in the form data.
 * @returns The function `prepareFormData` returns a `FormData` object.
 */
const prepareFormData = async (mideas, textMessage, category) => {
  const formData = new FormData();
  for (let midea of mideas) {
    const response = await fetch(midea.uri);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    // Get the last substring after the last dot
    const extension = midea.uri.substring(midea.uri.lastIndexOf("."));
    // Remove the leading dot from the extension
    const cleanExtension = extension.slice(1);
    // genarating a file name with uuid
    const fileName = await `${Crypto.randomUUID()}${extension}`;
    formData.append(midea.type, blob, {
      name: fileName,
      type: `${midea.type}/${cleanExtension}`,
    });
  }
  formData.append("content", textMessage);
  formData.append("category", category);
  return formData;
};

const createPost = async (data) => {
      // console.log(data);
      const token = await authStorage.getToken();
      const headers = {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        Cookie: token ? token : "",
      };
      const response = await axios.post(
        `${config.domain}/post&invitation/create`,
        data,
        {
          headers,
        }
      );
      return response.data;
    },

const data = await prepareFormData(mideas, postmsg, category);
createPost(data);
```

*Backend (Express.js):*

```
router.post("/create", adminOnly, async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.files); // Output: []
});
```

**Additional Information:**

*Content-Type header:* Set to multipart/form-data in the Axios request.
*Libraries/middleware:* Not using Multer or any other middleware for file uploads.
Full code: [fonntend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pIWtzyUE-wgdU6j8gNLTgZIUuZYn02R9/view?usp=sharing) and [backend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kMAsBJuW0wKEYt5SkI-Mwn8YljhKQHan/view?usp=sharing)

**Troubleshooting steps taken:**

Confirmed that the FormData object is populated correctly on the frontend.
Verified that the Axios request is reaching the server and has the correct headers.
Tried searching for similar issues online but haven't found a solution that works in my specific context.

**Questions:**

What could be causing the req.files array to be empty on the server?
Are any specific configurations or middleware required for handling file uploads in this setup (React Native Expo frontend with Express.js backend)?
Is there anything incorrect in my code that might be contributing to the issue?
Have others encountered similar issues in this environment, and if so, what solutions have been found?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!